# Protect Python Script With HWID In Android

Tags: python, termux, hwid

I want to protect my python script with HWID in android

I want so that only people who have HWID can access my script

example :

```
HWID = {
"63e2xxx57d94",
"87g5xxxh6388",
"6634xxx65h9f"
}
#How To Check This ?
XHWID = 'some id'  
if HWID == XHWID:
     print("Success")
else:
     print("Failed")
exit()
```

Comment: The code is incorrect use: if XHWID in HWID:

Comment: What's preventing users with "wrong" HWIDs from modifying your script to remove the check?